# Application IncomingHandler sometimes not receiving Service message

Tags: java, android, multithreading, socket.io, android-service

I'm building Android app and I'm struggling with handling reconnection.

So the flow is like this:
 1. Connect with token you already have
 2. User is connecting to server by socket.io
 2.a) You have active token
     - positive response from server => everybody is happy
 2.b) You have no token or the token is not in database
     - you have to get new token from another server
     - new request is made to do that
     - in response user is trying to connect one more time

## Now the code:

### Application

Main function I'm running to make sure everything is connected

```
public static boolean isSocketConnected = false; //declared in AndroidApplication
public static boolean isServiceBound = false;     //declared in AndroidApplication
public volatile boolean allowNextSocketConnection = true; //declared in same calss as _runMePlease_

private void runMePlease() { //running in new thread
  if (AndroidApplication.isServiceBound) {
            if (AndroidApplication.isSocketConnected) {
                allowNextSocketConnection = false;
                connected = true;
                Logger.log("WE ARE CONNECTED");
            } else {
                if(isNetworkAvailable()){
                        if(allowNextSocketConnection) {
                            allowNextSocketConnection = false;
                            AndroidApplication.sendDataToService(CONNECT);
                        } else {
                            Logger.log("WAITING FOR SERVICE RESPONSE");
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        runMePlease();
                }
  }
```

And this is what I'm running after new token is coming by:

```
public void setSocketNewToken(){
    AndroidApplication.isSocketConnected = false;
    allowNextSocketConnection = true;
}
```

And this is running after successful connection:

```
public void setSocketConnected(){
    Logger.log("SOCKET CONNECTED");
    AndroidApplication.isSocketConnected = true;
}
```

Everything runs smoothly on the first run and if I kill the server and reconnect it fast. But only after token expires and reconnection is made sometimes it's not connecting or it's connecting but still looping through *"WAITING FOR SERVICE RESPONSE"* and it shouldn't because we already have *isSocketConnected* on true.

Any ideas?

## EDIT

After putting ton of logs I can see now that there is a point where *runMePlease()* is working, I'm receiving update from service and it's not running *IncomingHandler*.

### AndroidApplication snippet (after implementing AtomicBoolean)

```
static class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case CONNECTED:
                    Logger.log("New connect");
                    isSocketConnected.set(true);
                    connectionManager.setSocketConnected();
                    break;
                case DISCONNECTED:
                    Logger.log("Disconnect");
                    connectionManager.setSocketDisconnected();
                    break;
                case REFRESH_TOKEN:
                    Logger.log("Refresh token");
                    new Thread("Try2Connect") {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            getNewToken();
                        }
                    }.start();

                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
```

### Service snippet

```
public Emitter.Listener connected = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Logger.log("CONNECT!!!!!!!!!");
        messengerSynchronizer.sendToApplication(CONNECTED, ""); // sending data back to AndroidApplication
    }
};
```

So basically after I'm running *runMePlease()*, and waiting in *Logger.log("WAITING FOR SERVICE RESPONSE");* the response is logged in *Emit.Listener connected* but the AndroidApplication is not running *CONNECTED* block code.
Thus it's working perfectly first time, after rerunning *runMePlease()* it's looping without any possibility to end.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked at the detailed flow but when you access `isSocketConnected` and `isServiceBound` from different threads you have to declare them `volatile` so that all the writes to it are immediately visible when reading them from another thread. Otherwise the thread may read cached values of those variables even though they were already changed in another thread.

Also when you have multple threads that can call `runMePlease()` then it would make sense to use AtomicBoolean for `allowNextSocketConnection` because otherwise with the following code

```
if(allowNextSocketConnection) {
    allowNextSocketConnection = false;
    // ...
```

two threads could enter the `if` when `allowNextSocketConnection` is `true`. To prevent this you can use the `compareAndSet(boolean expect, boolean update)` method so that only one thread can enter the `if`.

Comment: is there any other possibility to do this without volatile? Eg. synchronize?

Comment: Yes, but this is considerably more effort as you have to synchronize all accesses to the variable (reads and writes) with the same lock object. Alternatively you could also use an AtomicBoolean.

Comment: awesome, so I can use AtomicBoolean and it will be never "cached" value? I don't like making those variables volatiles as I have a lot of code that was running on statics and now I have to refactor A LOT :)

Comment: Yes, AtomicBoolean is ok.

Comment: great! One last thing: can I use it with static like
public static AtomicBoolean isServiceBound = new AtomicBoolean(true); I just can't believe it might be so easy without any drawback.

Comment: That's ok, but I am still not sure why you do not want to use `volatile` because you can have both `static` and `volatile`, they don't exclude each other. `AtomicBoolean` is used when you need to read and write a `boolean` in one atomic operation as `volatile` does not guarantee atomicity.

Comment: Looking at your code again, if you have multiple `runMePlease` threads then it would make sense to use `AtomicBoolean` for `allowNextSocketConnection` as you write to it depending on its previous value. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thank you very much for your help but sadly I still have problems with it :( it's not updating as it should but I found the probably issue, I've updated first post